# How can I read German characters (äöüß€) in Excel via PHPExcel?

Tags: php, utf-8, phpexcel

I'm reading this Excel file:

[image]

with [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com) but it looks like this:

[image]

I am using this code:

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile("data/".$file_name);
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly(array(0));
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("data/".$file_name);

echo '<table border="1">';
for ($row = 1; $row < $number_of_rows; $row++) {
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($column = 0; $column < $number_of_columns; $column++) {
        $value = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getCellByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getValue();
        echo '<td>';
        $newValue = iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", $value); //has no effect
        // echo $newValue . '&nbsp;';
        echo $value . '&nbsp;';
        echo '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
die;
```

**How can I read in the German characters from the Excel sheet correctly?**

Comment: Has the output-HTML the correct encoding (including the one the browser chooses)?

Comment: thanks, I forgot this was a test page which had no HTML headers or UTF-8 definitions on it, works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPExcel uses UTF-8 internally, so it will render all characters correctly if your html page is set as UTF-8

```
$newValue = iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", $value); //has no effect
```

won't work, because the characters are already UTF-8 and you're assuming they're ISO-8859-1